# How to filter nested parameters from Rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, actiondispatch

I see that I can filter keys from Rails logs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#log-filtering), but it's not entirely clear how I can filter a key that is nested inside the parameter hash.

My params hash looks like this:

```
{"download"=>{"attachment_id"=>"54039", "data"=>"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..."}}
```

Where `params[:download][:data]` is a base64 string. It is a large amount of data and I would like to remove it from my logs.

Is this possible?

I'm using Rails 4.0.4

Comment: did you try `config.filter_parameters << {download: :data}` ?

Comment: That way doesn't work. It should be used in form of a string and not an hash. For this case, `config.filter_parameters += ["download.data"]`, as it was pointed out by the accepted anwser for this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply put this in application.rb:

> config.filter_parameters += [:data]

This would filter nested [:data] keys also.

In rails 5, you can define hierarchy of the key:

> config.filter_parameters += ["download.data"]

This would filter all the [:data] keys which have [:download] as the immediate parent.

Comment: hmm, that works fairly well, but can I specify that `download` must be a top level key only?

Comment: No. But in Rails 5 you can define that download should be child of a specific parent key. Details here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13897

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most straight-forward way is to monkeypatch Rails code for parameter filtering in your `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`:

```
# monkeypatch to filter nested parameters
class ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter::CompiledFilter
  def call(original_params, path = [])
    filtered_params = {}

    original_params.each do |key, value|
      if regexps.any? { |r| key =~ r || (path + [key]).join('/') =~ r  }
        value = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter::FILTERED
      elsif value.is_a?(Hash)
        value = call(value, path + [key])
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        value = value.map { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? call(v, path + [key]) : v }
      elsif blocks.any?
        key = key.dup
        value = value.dup if value.duplicable?
        blocks.each { |b| b.call(key, value) }
      end

      filtered_params[key] = value
    end

    filtered_params
  end
end
```

and then:

`Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += ['download/data']`